# access Google spreadsheet using java core application without UI

Tags: google-drive-api, google-sheets-api

I am currently using OAuth 2.0 and Google APIs to authorize a user to download a spreadsheet saved in my google drive, programmatically. Although in this appproach the authorization code needs to be extracted from a URL, which opens up a web page that asks for user's Google Account Sign In. How do I do this **without having to login to a UI**, as my application is in the middle layer and and it can only do things programmatically. Am I missing anything over here? Is it even possible to download and/or access Spreadsheet using Google API without needing a UI Sign In?

Comment: No its not possible to access their spread sheet with out signin.  Oauth2 requires the web browser to open for authentication.

Comment: other then using Oauth2.0 is their any way at all.

Comment: no you must be authenticated to access google drive.

Comment: so cant this authentication be done pragmatically, also whatever happened to clientLogin,??? i just wanted to read the data from the file, dont want to modify anything..
what are the options I have, appreciate your quick responses.

Comment: Of course it can be done programmatically, but you will still have to display the browser to the user so they can authenticate.   The rest of the flow can be done programmatically.  Client Login is insecure.

Answer (score 0):

Yes its possible. Make the spreadsheet public. The official docs show you how to read from a public spreadsheet.
other options that dont require a public spreadsheet is to make your own service that acts as a middle layer to the spreadsheet. If you dont have a lot of users you can do that for free with an apps script content service. The user just does an ajax to the apps script piblished url to get the spreadsheet data which you can further cache with apps script cache service.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's very easy. You need to authorize your app one time with `offline=true` and store the refresh token. There is no need for the user to be logged in.